# Error while creating SPARK RDD (of file on HDFS) and calling Action

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

```
scala> val manager=sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/training/employee_dir/employeeManager")
scala> manager.first
```

ERROR:

```
java.io.EOFException: 
End of File Exception between local host is:
"localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1";
destination host is: "localhost":54310; :      
java.io.EOFException; For          more details
see:http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException
```

Do i need set any property `spark-home/conf`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem might occur if services including Java are not running. Please check all services are running. Furthermore, please check firewall permissions. Another reason might be something like this:

> hostname for hadoop as "xxx" not as "localhost"; you may want to check if the 
>   ip address in "/etc/hosts" for both "xxx" and "localhost" are correctly set.

Whatever you do, please take a backup of your files and check at your risk.